# Why do two figure objects appear instead of one?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I run this function,

```
def plot_data(df, title="", xlabel="", ylabel="", figsize=(12, 8), save_figure=False):
    from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
    fontP = FontProperties()
    fontP.set_size('small')
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)

    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper left', prop=fontP)
    plt.grid()

    df.plot()
    plt.show()

    if save_figure:
        plt.savefig(title)
```

the result looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why two figure objects come up. And it looks like `legend`, `grid` are not applied appropriately...

Also, I want to clearly know about "when figure object created" or "how can I create just one figure object without confusion" kind of thing. Is there any good tutorial for this?

Comment: I think the last paragraph is a bit too broad, especially if you mix `matplotlib` and `pandas`. There are some tutorials for matplotlib (i.e. https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes is a good starting point) but how they directly relate to `pandas` is more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), by default, doesn't use the current active figure but creates a new figure. But that's just default behavior - You can override it by explicitly passing the active axes (`ax` argument) in:

```
df.plot(ax=plt.gca())  # gca stands for "get currently axes" instance
```

Or you can simply put the `df.plot` command at the top because (unlike `df.plot`) most `plt` functions modify the current active figure and some `plt` commands (e.g. `legend`) even won't work if there's no "plot" yet:

```
def plot_data(df, title="", xlabel="", ylabel="", figsize=(12, 8), save_figure=False):

    # Moved to the top
    df.plot()

    from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
    fontP = FontProperties()
    fontP.set_size('small')
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)

    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper left', prop=fontP)
    plt.grid()

    plt.show()

    if save_figure:
        plt.savefig(title)
```